# How to: use a specific app from a different project as a dep

Tags: erlang, rebar3

I'm trying to compile my app (app_1) with a dep from another project (proj2) which has some apps (e.g. app_a, app_b, app_c...).

proj2 is has an apps folder in which there are the said apps (app_a etc.).

I'm trying to get app_a, but it also depends on app_b.
Whatever I do, I cannot seem to get it to work.

Using this in rebar.config of app_1:

```
{deps, [{proj2, {git, "git://github.com/scm/pr/proj2", {branch, "master"}}}]}.
```

I get

```
Dependency failure: source for proj2 does not contain a recognizable project and can not be built
```

Similar attempts with app_a instead of proj2, adding the /apps/app_a path etc. do not help.
Running rebar3 3.12.0.

Any help would be appreciated in how is it possible. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With rebar3 3.12.0, I don't think this is possible.  You might be able to get it to work by using a `rebar3.config.script` file that downloads the dependency manually before putting it somewhere rebar3 can find it.

---

rebar3 3.14.0 introduced a `git_subdir` dependency type, which would look something like this:

```
{deps, [{proj2, {git_subdir, "git://github.com/scm/pr", {branch, "master"}, "proj2"}}]}.
```

This is mentioned in an example in the [documentation on dependencies](https://rebar3.org/docs/configuration/dependencies/), but there aren't many details about it.

So if you're able to upgrade to a newer rebar3 version, it might be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I upgraded to 3.14 and with git_subdir solved the issue.